# How to assign UITextfield position inside of SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitextfield

When I assign the `CGRect` parameter in the `SKScene` like below, it disappears:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

var username = defaults.string(forKey: "usernameSaved")

class SetupScene: SKScene{

var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField();

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)


    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pixelBackground")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.size = self.size
    background.zPosition = -10
    self.addChild(background)

    self.view?.addSubview(myTextField)
    myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 230.00, height: 33.00));
    myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    myTextField.placeholder = "Enter Name Here:"
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
    myTextField.textAlignment = .center
    myTextField.font = UIFont(name: "04b_25", size: 25)
    myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myTextField.center = (self.view?.center)!


}
```

But, when I set the parameters before the `SKScene`, like below, it shows up at the top left of the screen.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

var username = defaults.string(forKey: "usernameSaved")

class SetupScene: SKScene{

var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 230.00, height: 33.00));



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)


    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pixelBackground")
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.size = self.size
    background.zPosition = -10
    self.addChild(background)

    self.view?.addSubview(myTextField)

    myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    myTextField.placeholder = "Enter Name Here:"
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
    myTextField.textAlignment = .center
    myTextField.font = UIFont(name: "04b_25", size: 25)
    myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myTextField.center = (self.view?.center)!
}
```

My goal is to be able to modify it after the `SKScene` has begun because I want to have its height be `self.size.height/2`. However, I can't do it before `SKScene` because it gives me the error:

> self. doesn't exist yet.

But I can't seem to find a way to edit its location after the scene is established.

Comment: You are aware that UITextField is not a part of SpriteKit, but UIKit.  As for your issues, in scenario 1, you add a different textfield then the one you created.  The order of your code is important,  You are basically saying add old textfield followed by create new text field

Comment: Yea I know that UITextField is part of UIKit. I didnt realize I was creating a new text field after creating the initial one outside the SKView. How can I move the UITextfields location after the SKView has been created then?

Comment: You are already moving it.... I am not sure what you are doing, but your approach is bad.  You are going to come into problems when handling the different screen sizes.